# Constant ACPI errors in /var/log/messages on Centos 6.10

Tags: centos, centos6, bios, acpi

/var/log/messages is full of this, occurring every second.  I can see this has been going on for at least 4 days but any older logs have been purged.  Maybe it's always been like this.

```
Jul  8 04:07:12 webbox1 kernel: ACPI Error: SMBus or IPMI write requires Buffer of length 66, found length 32 (20090903/exfield-286)
Jul  8 04:07:12 webbox1 kernel: ACPI Error (psparse-0537): Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff88087468bab0), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT
Jul  8 04:07:12 webbox1 kernel: ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20090903/power_meter-342)
```

Can someone explain what it means, or where I should look to debug further?

Thanks

Comment: 95% of the time this is a BIOS bug and requires a BIOS update to fix. But to be sure, you should file a bug report at kernel.org.

Comment: In that instance would it be safe to somehow silence these messages, so /var/log/messages can be useful again, rather than a multiple-MB behemoth every day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a common problem with some older HPE servers.

The first thing you should do is update the system BIOS/firmware.

If the updated firmware doesn't resolve the problem, you can work around the problem by disabling the [ACPI power meter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hwmon/acpi_power_meter) module, e.g.:

```
echo "blacklist acpi_power_meter" >> /etc/modprobe.d/hwmon.conf
```

In pre-3.0 kernels such as that in CentOS 6, the module name was just `power_meter`:

```
echo "blacklist power_meter" >> /etc/modprobe.d/hwmon.conf
```

In theory it's possible to write a custom ACPI table to patch the problem yourself, but that's more than a bit complicated, and it's something the hardware vendor should have fixed anyway...

Comment: This is a dedicated server that I get from oneprovider.com and their management interface says "Don't change BIOS, RAID, IDRAC, ILO configuration!" - I guess I'll send them a ticket and see if they fancy doing it for me...

Comment: Aha. Well, they should take care of this immediately or you should get a refund...

Comment: Thanks, I've had the box with them for a number of years now and would certainly prefer not to have to move it.  I'll open a ticket, thank you.

Comment: Oh, well in that case it's probably not their fault it hasn't had a BIOS update in years :)

Comment: Unfortunately a newer BIOS didn't make a difference.  Are there any risks/downsides to disabling the ACPI power meter like you suggested?  Thanks!

Comment: @Codemonkey You won't be able to monitor the system's power usage (in watts) from within the OS. If it's a leased server, you might not care much about that though.

Comment: I care less than not at all, thanks! :)

Comment: I ran that command Michael and have checked that the file exists and contains what it should, but my log file is still filling up with these messages.  I tried a reboot too, no difference.  Sorry...

Comment: Hmm. You have a really old kernel; it may have been named `power_meter` and not `acpi_power_meter`.

Comment: Will it definitely be coming from hwmon, it couldn't be coming from another service like netdata? I've just tried disabling sensors in netdata and it didn't seem to make a difference - I'll try `power_meter` now.  Do I need a reboot to see the effects or is there a service I can restart instead?

Comment: @Codemonkey You'll have to reboot to blacklist the module.

Comment: Perfect, `power_meter` did the trick, thanks for all your help.